# How do I show either an image or text in a GridView cell (or bind an image to a certain cell's tooltip) depending on the data type?

Tags: wpf, dynamic, data-binding

I have a dictionary of string -> object, where the object can hold several value types such as a string or a bitmap

I've successfully bound the dictionary to a DataGrid, but I want to convert the bitmap values so that they'd display the image (either in-cell, or in a tooltip when hovering over the cell) instead of saying "System.Drawing.Bitmap".

Here's my code:

```
public class MyView : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MyView() {
            Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            Data["name 1"] = "value 1";
            Data["name 2"] = new Bitmap("C:\\test.bmp");
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Data"));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        

        public IDictionary<string, object> Data { set; get; }


    }
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <src:MyView x:Key="myView"/>
        <src:EnumerableConverter x:Key="enumerableConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myView}, Path=Data}" ToolTip="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType=AccessText}}">
                
            </DataGrid>


        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm not sure how to go about this. I've seen it applied to a whole column:

```xml
<DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

But in my case, the same column would display both text and images.

And I know how to set the tooltip for the whole datagrid, but how do I make it change depending on cell content? And how do I make it display an image?

Comment: Use 2 datatemplates with different DataType Property. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the `Bitmap` with a "WPF friendly" `BitmapImage` in your class:

```
public class MyView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyView()
    {
        Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Data["name 1"] = "value 1";
        Data["name 2"] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\test.bmp"));
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Data"));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public IDictionary<string, object> Data { set; get; }
}
```

...you could use a custom `DataTemplate` and a `DataTemplateSelector` to display the image:

```
public class Selector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ImageTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is BitmapImage && ImageTemplate != null)
            return ImageTemplate;

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myView}, Path=Data}" ToolTip="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType=AccessText}}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="imageTemplate">
            <Image Source="{Binding }" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <src:Selector x:Key="selector" ImageTemplate="{StaticResource imageTemplate}" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Value}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```